# How to set context path in Spring Boot running in AppEngine Standard

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine, servlets

Is there a way to set a context path in a Spring Boot application running in GCP AppEngine Standard?

I want to add an implicit prefix to all my resources. So if the `@RestController`s are, say, `/a` and `/b`, I want that to access them, their URL is always `/my/prefix/a` and `/my/prefix/b`. In normal, embedded mode in Spring Boot, this works by setting `server.servlet.context-path`. However, this setting is not respected by AppEngine. In it, `/my/prefix/a` returns a 404 and I have to use `/a` instead

How do I add a common prefix to all my resources in AppEngine Standard? This seems basic for AppEngine's services/modules support to avoid duplicating the prefix in all controllers, but I can't find how to do it

Answer (score 2):

so per my conversation with the Google Cloud Support team - I got confirmation that the App Engine Standard does not support / honor the port & context paths set in spring-boot.

This is the response I got from them:

"With regards to your concern about App Engine not honoring the manually set port number and context path, this is because it should be setup in yaml file.

For the port to be set as 7777, it should be done by port forwarding. However, port forwarding is only available in App Engine Flex. For more details about this, you may visit this page [1].

For the context-path, you may use the  tag and include in appengine-web.xml file. This sets the path in your application that contains the static files. You may check this document [2] for more information.

You could also include the  tag in your appengine-web.xml as it is also useful for serving static content such as images, CSS stylesheets or JavaScript files. You may use this reference [3].

With this solution or workaround, this also address that spring-boot application could be deployed in App Engine.

If you have further concerns, just let me know.

Thank you and have a nice day!

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#port_forwarding
[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#public_root
[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#static_files
"

However, setting the  to some value did not still pick it up as the context path. So had to abandon GAE unfortunately. Wasted so much time on this - hope this is useful for others that are struggling with this.